# Clojure macro to process multiple function metadata

Tags: macros, clojure, metadata, defn

In Clojure, how do I make a library macro which processes supplied functions metadata and return some result? Amount of functions is unlimited and they should be passed without being boxed into a sequence (`(my-macro fn1 fn2)` instead of `(my-macro [fn1 fn2])`)

Say, we expect function vars having :foo keys in meta and the macro concatenates their values. The following snippet should work in REPL (considering `my-macro` is in the namespace):

```
user=> (defn my-func-1 {:foo "bar"} [])
(defn my-func-1 {:foo "bar"} [])
#'user/my-func-1
user=> (defn my-func-2 {:foo "baz"} [])
(defn my-func-2 {:foo "baz"} [])
#'user/my-func-2
user=> (my-macro my-func-1 my-func2)
(my-macro my-func-1 my-func2)
"barbaz"
```

I tried several approaches but was only able to process single function so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defmacro my-macro [& fns]
  `(clojure.string/join (list ~@(map (fn [x] `(:foo (meta (var ~x)))) fns))))

(defn ^{:foo "bar"} my-func-1 [])
(defn ^{:foo "baz"} my-func-2 [])
(my-macro my-func-1 my-func-2) ;; => "barbaz"
```

### How it Works

If you expand the macro you can start to see the parts in play.

```
(macroexpand '(my-macro my-func-1 my-func-2))

(clojure.string/join
  (clojure.core/list (:foo (clojure.core/meta (var my-func-1)))
                     (:foo (clojure.core/meta (var my-func-2)))))
```

```
(var my-func-1)
```

Function metadata is stored on the var, so using `(meta my-func-1)` is not sufficient. But, [`var`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#var) is a special form and does not compose like a normal function.

```
(fn [x] `(:foo (meta (var ~x))))
```

This anonymous function exists inside an escaped form, so it is processed inside the macro to produce the output forms. Internally it will create a the `(:foo (meta (var my-func-1)))` form by first backtick escaping the outer form to declare it a literal, and not evaluated, list and then unescaping the `x` var with a tilde to output the value instead of the symbol.

```
`(clojure.string/join (list ~@(map (fn [x] `(:foo (meta (var ~x))))
                                   fns)))
```

This entire form is backtick escaped, so it will be returned literally. But, I still need to evaluate the map function generating the `(:foo (meta (var my-func-1)))` form. In this case I have unescaped, and spliced (`@`) the result of, the `map` form directly. This first evaluates the map function and returns a list of generated forms, and then takes the contents of that list and splices it into the parent list.

```
(defmacro test1 [x] `(~x))
(defmacro test2 [x] `(~@x))

(macroexpand '(test1 (1 2 3))) ;; => ((1 2 3))
(macroexpand '(test2 (1 2 3))) ;; => (1 2 3)
```

You could also split out the `map` function in a `let` statement before hand for slightly more readability.

```
(defmacro my-macro [& fns]
  (let [metacalls (map (fn [x] `(:foo (meta (var ~x)))) fns)]
    `(clojure.string/join (list ~@metacalls))))
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you passing an empty string to `clojure.string/join`?

Comment: Fixed the answer to remove it. While writing the macro I had a separator, but I forgot to remove the argument. Thanks for the comment.